# How do I Move a List of Users to a Voice Channel using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that automatically makes 2 teams and moves each team to their own voice channel. I made two lists which represent the teams. I tried to use a for loop to move all of the users to their voice calls. However, when I run this, I get this error message: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'move_to'`. I also tried printing the userID, and I get just the userID that I should get according to the resources I have seen.

Here are the parts of the code I am talking about:

```
if msg == "!start" and matchmaking:
    members = hub.members
    memids = []
    for member in members:
      memids.append(member.id)
    print(memids)

    random.shuffle(memids)

    team1 = memids[:3]
    team2 = memids[3:]

    print(team1)
    print(team2)

    for x in team1:
      await x.move_to(vc1)
    for x in team2:
      await x.move_to(vc2)
```

Comment: The teams only have the memberids in them, you likely want the whole member object.

Comment: @Oso How do I go from an ID to the whole member?

Comment: Make the teams using `members` instead of first extracting the ids like you do in the `for member in members` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`move_to` is an attribute of member object not its id (which is an int), so just replace the following:

```
if msg == "!start" and matchmaking:
    members = hub.members
    # it's fine to use directly List[Member]
 
    random.shuffle(members)

    team1 = members[:3]
    team2 = members[3:]

    print(team1)
    print(team2)

    for x in team1:
      await x.move_to(vc1)
    for x in team2:
      await x.move_to(vc2)

    # and in case you want some member id for some reason
    memids = list(map(lambda x: x.id, members))
    # or just
    members[i].id
```